# Django keeps reporting the same error after I already edited views.py

Tags: django, process, uwsgi

I am editing a Django 2.2 application and I received an Exception:

> TypeError at `/myappname/myurl`
> 'RelatedManager' object is not iterable
> Exception Location: `/myprojectlocation/myappname/views.py` in `myview`, line 41

Whoops, I accidentally typed `.objects` instead of `.objects.all()`. Easy fix.

But now, no matter how I edit `views.py`, I keep receiving the exact same exception, always pointing at line 41. I even commented line 41 out entirely, and still get the same exception. The exception Traceback shows the updated line 41, so I know I am definitely editing the right file and the changes are being saved, but the actual exception itself just keeps complaining about that RelatedManager no matter what I edit.

I've restarted the webserver and I've cleared all my browsing data. So what on earth is still "remembering" the old code that I've edited many times since?

---

**Update:** Everything is fine on the django development server (`manage.py runserver`). So apparently it's more of a uWSGI/nginx problem than anything I'm doing wrong with my django files.

Comment: You can try to remove the `*.pyc` files, this is bytecode the interpreter produces to skip parsing the code the next time.

Comment: From `/myappname/__pycache__`? Deleted, no change—and it doesn't look as though the `.pyc` files have been recreated.

Comment: Does it also persist even if you do a complete system powercycle?

Comment: @jchung I'm running on Opalstack shared hosting so I can't try that experiment.

Comment: Update: I set up ssh port-forwarding so I could run the django development server, and everything is fine there. So it seems to be a uWSGI/nginx problem and not a problem with any of my django code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that somehow my `tmp/uwsgi.pid` file wound up with the wrong process ID in its contents, so I was unwittingly failing to stop the master uWSGI process when I thought I was restarting the Django application.

I used `pstree -p` to see my process hierarchy and get the correct process ID of the master uWSGI process, edited `uwsgi.pid` to contain that correct ID, used `pkill -9 -f \path\to\my\application` to kill the process, and finally restarted my application again.